# gulp reporter to file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Here is my configuration:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
// load plugins
$ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('scripts', function () {
  return gulp.src([
      'app/scripts/**/*.js',
      'gulpfile.js',
      'protractor.conf.js',
      'test/**/*.js'
    ])
    .pipe($.jshint())
    .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-junit-reporter'))
    .pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
    .pipe($.size());
});
```

jshint-junit-reporter must output to a file, I already tried:

```
.pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-junit-reporter').pipe(gulp.dest('output.xml')))
```

and

```
.pipe($.jshint.reporter('jshint-junit-reporter')).pipe(gulp.dest('output.xml'))
```

but it just redirect the gulp.src to a directory with the name: output.xml

Answer (score 0):

I made found a workaround for this limitation.

Make sure to `npm install --save jshint jshint-junit-reporter gulp-shell`

You'll also want to make sure you have a `.jshintrc` file where you run gulp.

Then in your `gulpfile.js`

```
var shell = require('gulp-shell')
gulp.task('lint-tofile', shell.task(
    ["node_modules/.bin/jshint www/js/ --reporter=node_modules/jshint-junit-reporter/reporter.js > test/results/lint.xml"], 
    { cwd: __dirname, ignoreErrors: true }
));
```

You'll need to alter the "www/js" and "test/results/lint.xml" bits.

Also I've made a [pull request to the jshint-junit-reporter](https://github.com/xjamundx/jshint-junit-reporter/pull/8) maintainer with a new outputFile option.

Answer (score 0):

I think a custom js hint reporter is what you're after. Try adapting the following to your needs:

```
var fs = require('fs'); // Native Node package
var mapStream = require('map-stream'); // Install via npm

gulp.task('js:lint', function(){
    var jsHintReporter = function (taskName) {
        var toWrite = [];
        var stream = mapStream(function (file, cb) {
            var noErrors = true;
            if (!file.jshint.success) {
                var message = 'JSLINT fail in ' + file.path;
                noErrors = false;
                console.log(message);

                file.jshint.results.forEach(function (err) {
                    var filePathDirs = err.file.split('/');
                    var filePath = filePathDirs.slice(
                        filePathDirs.length - 2,
                        filePathDirs.length
                    ).join('/');

                    if (err.error) {
                        var errorMessage = '' + filePath + ': line ' + err.error.line + ' | col ' + err.error.character + ' | ' + err.error.reason;
                        toWrite.push(errorMessage);
                        console.log(errorMessage);
                    }
                });
            }

            if (noErrors) {
                var message = taskName + ': 0 issues!';
                toWrite.push(message);
                console.log(message);
            }

            fs.writeFile('jsLintOutput.txt', toWrite.join('\n'))

            cb(null, file);
        });

        return stream;
    };
    var reporter = new jsHintReporter('js:lint');
    var stream = gulp.src('resources/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(gp.jshint())
        .pipe(reporter);

    return stream;
});
```